# How can I embed a video in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I embed a video into element in React?

This is what I have tried so far.

```
<video autoPlay={true} loop={true} id="intro">
  <source src="video here" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: What issues are you having with your current code? What does it do?

Comment: You can write plain HTML in JSX so nothing about this is React specific. Also what's the issue with what you've tried, what issues are you getting, error messages, etc.

Comment: I dont serve static files intro public dir.

Comment: What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this helps:

```
import { DefaultPlayer as Video } from 'react-html5video';
import 'react-html5video/dist/styles.css';
render() {
    return (
        <Video autoPlay loop muted
            controls={['PlayPause', 'Seek', 'Time', 'Volume', 'Fullscreen']}
            poster="Your poster here"
            onCanPlayThrough={() => {
                // Do stuff
            }}>
            <source src="video here" type="video/mp4" />
            <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srcLang="en" src="http://source.vtt" default />
        </Video>
    );
}
```

For more details refer here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5video

Comment: You can place the intro tag right after muted like this <Video autoPlay loop muted id = "intro" .......................}}>